# can nginx (without or with special plugins) serve a "slow" / "delayed" 404

Tags: nginx

for certain urls I'd like nginx to return a 'slow' 404.

Example:

nginx will reply to `/special_path/non_existing` with a 404, but only after 5 seconds

can nginx do this without / with a plugin?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37163561/212107) using the [`echo_sleep`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_sleep) directive. It's a separate plugin though.

Comment: this looks perfect. let's see if the echo plugin exists on the servers I am using

Comment: whats the best way to proceed?

We wait a little longer? You post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752943/using-nginx-to-simulate-slow-response-time-for-testing-purposes/37163561#37163561), you can use the [`echo_sleep`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_sleep) directive from the `echo` module.

```
location /special_path/non_existing {
   echo_sleep 1;
   return 404;
}
```

Comment: Just recently I noticed, that above suggested configuration doesn't really perform the delay.

It is a valid configuration and doesn't cause errors but the delay is not performed.